# Internet - Prioritise Wifi connection over 3G Modem

Tags: networking, wifi

I have:

1. A Raspberry Pi 3B SBC
2. I have a Huawei E5330 3G Wifi router connected to the Pi via USB
3. I have a Wireless router connected to my internet line (fibre)
4. I have set a static IP address for my Pi's connection to the internet Wifi router
5. I can connect to the Pi using SSH using that static IP

I have the challenge that when the Pi tries to access the internet (e.g,  when running `sudo apt-get update`), it uses the Huawei modem's connection.

**I want it to use the fibre's Wifi router connection(not connect through the Huawei 3G one)**.

**What I have tried:**

1. Ran `$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 wlan0` based on [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8020/97546)

Ran **netstat -rn**, and got the following result, where **192.168.1.1** is my fibre line's Wifi router and **192.168.8.1** is my 3G router

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enx001e101f0000
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enx001e101f0000
```

Then Ran **rote**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
default         www.huaweimobil 0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 enx001e101f0000
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 enx001e101f0000
```

I don't want to mess up the configs, if I haven't already, so any help would be appreciated on **how I can make all internet requests to go through my fibre's Wifi router (192.168.1.1)**

Answer (score 3):

You have three default routes. Only one default route can be used. Which one is determined by the metric. The route with the lowest metric wins. You have used deprecated command `route` that sets a metric of 0 if not specified. Now it is somewhat unclear what a metric of 0 means. Does it have the highest priority? It seems not to be in all cases. I have found a discussion about this at [In Linux, what metric has a route with no metric?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/425924/243074). You should better use more up to date command `ip route`.

The best is you omit using metric 0 to avoid confusing. But with your problem you do not have to care about metric at all. You add a default route but instead you should delete one. There is already a default route to the internet router:

```
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
```

It has only a lower metric than the one to the USB 3G router so it isn't used. You should just delete the default route to the 3G router with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo ip route del default via 192.168.8.1 dev enx001e101f000
```

Then you only have one default route to the internet router.

To make this persistent you have to modify `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` (I suppose you are using default network setup). Just add this two lines:

```
interface enx001e101f000
nogateway
```

Here are some details about this [Can I prevent a default route being added when bringing up an interface?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333610/243074).

Comment: Thank-you for responding. I had no idea the `route` command was depracted. Thanks for that....Sorry to also ask what may be somewhat obvious to you, but **how is this done**. How do I delete the default route. I am a total beginner in many things Raspberry and *nix.

Comment: @user919426 No problem :-) That's the Raspberry Pi made for. I have given you the command `sudo ip route del ...`. But I also have updated the answer to configure it persistent in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: Thank-you for that and for the persistent config. Trying it out

Comment: It tells me  `inet address is expected rather than "www.huaweimobil"`.  I assume I have to type `sudo ip route del default via 192.168.8.1 dev enx001e101f000`... based on http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html#tools-ip-route-del

Comment: @user919426 Yes, seems I have given a wrong advice. Does it work with 192.168.8.1? Check with `ip route`. It should show you only one default route.

Comment: I went ahead and ran the command using the IP address. No error. Rebooted the pi. Tested it, same issue. Internet requests still going through the 3G modem. Ran `ip route` and it shows that `enx001e101f0000`has metric `204` vs the other one havig metric `303`. Is it correct to assume that the **3G modem is being prioritised**?

Comment: @user919426 Yes, you are correct. 204 is lower than 303, so that route is taken. If you have this then just delete the route with metric 204. Now it should go through the other route with metric 303 to the internet router.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments by Ingo you should list how you set a static IP address (many people do this incorrectly) - or better still don’t set one.

This may prevent routing from working properly.

In general Ethernet interfaces are preferentially used.